# Mongoose: how to query by a key of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this

```
const CustomersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  merchant:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true,
    ref: 'Merchent'
  },
  idCustomer:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim:true,
    //unique: true
  }, 
  customerData:{
   type:Object,
   required:true
  }
});
```

and customerData looks like

```
{
   "name": "Other",
   "birthday": null,
   "age": null,
   "createdAt": "2019-04-01T20:01:04.000Z",
   "email": null,
   "visits": 0,
   "payments": "0.00",
   "lastVisit": "2019-12-16T12:58:09.000Z",
}
```

Is there a way I can query by customerData.name and if it doesn't exist it won't cause errors

Right now I do

```
let query = {
    merchant: merchant._id,
    'customerData.name': req.query.name
}
Customer.find(query)
  .then(...)
```

but this way if there is no query.name no documents return

Edit: also regex won't do because I will need to search by numbers(ex: customerData.visits) in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you need to return the document whether or not you have `query.name` and if there is `query.name` the query will consider that and if there is no `query.name` it will not take that into account. So, you can setup a small logic for that. Something like this:

```
let query = {
  merchant: merchant._id
};
// we only set the query for the customerData.name if query.name exist
if(req.query.name) {
  query['customerData.name'] = req.query.name;
}
Customer.find(query)
  .then(...)
```